# Setting Chrome to render ASP.Net mobile

Tags: asp.net, mobile, browser

I am using the functionality in ASP.Net where it detects if the browser is on a mobile device and redirects to the page that has *.mobile.cshtml.  This is all working great as long as I'm actually using a mobile device, but I can't seem to figure out how to get Chrome or Firefox to use the *.Mobile.cshtml files instead of the standard .cshtml files.

I've tried setting the Chrome emulation to use iPhone, but it is still rendering my standard pages.

Is there some setting in VS or Chrome that will tell ASP.Net to render the mobile version?

Comment: See if this helps: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation

Comment: Perfect!  It looks like you have to go to the User Agent section and turn on the Spoof user agent to send the correct header.